# initializing a tensorflow hub module variables and tables once for all that have speed for being used in restful api backend

Tags: tensorflow, initialization, tensorflow-hub

hello guys i have a problem that i can't find best way to do it

i have a backend restful api and i want to use a tensorflow hub module in it but i have a problem and that is every time i want to do a calculation i must initialize all of variables and tables and it took a lot of time to process and my question is:

is there a way that i can initialize all of variables and tables once for all in a session and close the session because a way to solve this problem is to keep open the session and do calculations but the problem with my solution is that it occupy resources.

i put both the main code and my own solution for better understanding

## function for loading different module

```
def loading_module(path = None, module_url = 
                   'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2'):
    # Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    if path == None:
        embed_object = hub.Module(module_url)
    else:
        embed_object = hub.Module(hub.load_module_spec(path))
    return embed_object
```

## function for run embedding module on text

```
def run_embedding(embed_object, graph, text):
    # Reduce logging output.
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
    with tf.Session(graph = graph) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        similarity_input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
        encoding_tensor = embed_object(similarity_input_placeholder)
        message_embeddings = sess.run(encoding_tensor, feed_dict = {similarity_input_placeholder:text})

    return message_embeddings

embed_object = loading_module()
run_embedding(embed_object, ['sth'])
```

## my solution

```
def loading_module(path = None, module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2'):
    # Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        if path == None:
            embed_object = hub.Module(module_url)
        else:
            embed_object = hub.Module(hub.load_module_spec(path))
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph = g)
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])

    return embed_object, g, sess


def run_embedding(embed_object, graph, sess, text):
    # Reduce logging output.
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
    with graph.as_default():
        similarity_input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
        encoding_tensor = embed_object(similarity_input_placeholder)
        message_embeddings = sess.run(encoding_tensor, feed_dict = {similarity_input_placeholder:text})

    return message_embeddings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split graph building and session construction from session execution. E.g.:

```
def make_embed_fn(module):
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
    embed = hub.Module(module)
    embeddings = embed(sentences)
    session = tf.train.MonitoredSession()
  return lambda x: session.run(embeddings, {sentences: x})

embed_fn = make_embed_fn('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2')
embed_fn(["hello 1"])
embed_fn(["hello 2"])
embed_fn(["hello 3"])
...
```

Additionally, note that both hub.Module() and hub.load_module_spec can be called both with paths and with https urls, you don't need to have the conditions and wrapping as you have in your original `loading_module`. E.g.:

```
# These two are valid uses of the API:
hub.Module("/tmp/my_local_module")
hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/...")
```

Comment: i have a question: if i want to use this multiple time i have to not close the session so my question is if i don't close the session it consume the ram or not?

Comment: a session consumes ram. After all it represents among others the weights loaded in memory and tensorflow ready to execute the graph.

Comment: but when i run operation embed_fn(["hello 1"]) usage of the ram increases but when the operation done the usage of the ram decreases to the same level that was before the operation so it seems the session is closed. i have another question also